# Show next/previous in control center for UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, youtube, uiwebview

When i load any youtube video in UIWebView, the next/previous buttons in control centre become disappear. 
I want to load videos in UIWebView by keeping next/previous buttons in control centre.

**Example(Nothing fancy):**

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Pn874kEc3IA";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

[image: Screenshot]

**NOTE:** The behaviour is same in the real device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable next and previous tracks.

```
MPRemoteCommandCenter *rcc = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
MPRemoteCommand *nextTrackCommand = [rcc nextTrackCommand];
[nextTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
[nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(nextTrackCommandAction)];

MPRemoteCommand *previousTrackCommand = [rcc previousTrackCommand];
[previousTrackCommand setEnabled:YES];
[previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(previousTrackCommandAction)];
```