# Disable the next and previous controls in iOS Webview videos

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using Webview to play the video its working as expected.
I wanted to hide the next and previous controls.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do this.

I tried this

```
 [html appendFormat:@"video { webkit-media-controls: none}"];
```

this one is not working can anyone please help on this.

Thanks,
Jitendra

Comment: My main question is why use a WebView to play a movie and not Movie player?

Comment: Working on old code someone did that I only want to solve this issue.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718424/show-next-previous-in-control-center-for-uiwebview

Comment: @rckoenes do you have any idea how to do this.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik that one is not useful.